# Uncaught (in promise) Provided element is not within a Document

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to screenshot  and download it to server, but still getting error. It´s a Wordpress BTW.

> Uncaught (in promise) Provided element is not within a Document

jQuery

```
<script>
function takeScreenshot(){
var element = jQuery("#vpc-preview");
html2canvas(element,{
background:'#FFFFFF',
onrendered:function(canvas){
var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
$.ajax({
url:'/wp-content/plugins/html2canvas/save.php',
type:'post',
dataType:'text',
data:{base64data:imgData}
});
}
});
}
</script>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`element` in your code is a jQuery object, not an element

Try

```
var element = jQuery("#vpc-preview")[0];
```